# Filter values from multidimensional object/array into a sorted multidimentsional array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I want to filter out of a multidemensional array all Stations, Rooms and Beds. Each array element of this multidemensional array contains one type of them. E.g. Element 1 is a station, Element 2 is a bed, etc.

My goal is to filter out the data that I need and to put the data into a new multidimensional array that have to look like this:

```
 0 => [
     id => 1234,
     name => "UB",
     rooms => [
       0 => [
         id => 1234,
         name => "01",
         beds => [
           0 => [
             id => 1234
             name => "09"
           ],
         ]
       ],
       1 => [
         id => 1234,
         name => "01",
         beds => [
           0 => [
             id => 1234
             name => "09"
           ],
         ]
       ]
     ]
   ],
   1 => [
     id => 1234,
     name => "UB",
     rooms => [
       0 => [
         id => 1234,
         name => "01",
         beds => [
           0 => [
             id => 1234
             name => "09"
           ],
           1 => [
             id => 12345
             name => "092"
           ],
         ]
       ],
       1 => [
         id => 1234,
         name => "01",
         beds => [
           0 => [
             id => 1234
             name => "09"
           ],
         ]
       ]
     ]
   ]]
```

The structure is like: There are multiple stations, each stations can have multiple rooms and each room can have multiple beds.

I have tried lots of different ways, but haven't found any working solution.

How I can do that?

Comment: Your data looks like it represent *objects*, not tabular data. So you should process it as objects. Using a multi dimensional array does not really make any sense. If the goal is to show objects as a table in a UI, you should ask how to do *that*

Comment: puting *I have tried lots of different ways* without providing those ways in most cases means **I tried nothing**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say we have something like this (as long as you haven't provided and example code):

```
public class Station
{
    public Station() { Rooms = new List<Room>(); }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
}

public class Room
{
    public Room() { Beds = new List<Bed>(); }
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public List<Bed> Beds { get; set; }
}

public class Bed
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Capacity { get; set; }
}
```

and we have a list of `Station`s like below:

```
List<Station> list = new List<Station>()
{
    new Station()
    {
        Id = 100,
        Rooms  = new List<Room>()
        {
            new Room
            {
                Id = 1500,
                Beds = new List<Bed>
                {
                    new Bed { Id = 1, Capacity = 2 },
                    new Bed { Id = 3, Capacity = 9 },
                    new Bed { Id = 2, Capacity = 6 },
                }
            },
            new Room
            {
                Id = 1800,
                Beds = new List<Bed>
                {
                    new Bed { Id = 9, Capacity = 3 },
                    new Bed { Id = 19, Capacity = 7 },
                    new Bed { Id = 20, Capacity = 12 },
                }
            },
        }
    },
    new Station()
    {
        Id = 99,
        Rooms  = new List<Room>()
        {
            new Room
            {
                Id = 1900,
                Beds = new List<Bed>
                {
                    new Bed { Id = 10, Capacity = 2 },
                    new Bed { Id = 30, Capacity = 9 },
                    new Bed { Id = 17, Capacity = 6 },
                }
            },
            new Room
            {
                Id = 2000,
                Beds = new List<Bed>
                {
                    new Bed { Id = 11, Capacity = 3 },
                    new Bed { Id = 4, Capacity = 7 },
                    new Bed { Id = 8, Capacity = 19 },
                }
            },
        }
    }};
```

I have provided a lots of kind of filters you will be able to do this structure:

```
var a = list.OrderBy(P => P.Id); // Sort by StationId (min .. to .. max) 
var b = list.OrderByDescending(P => P.Id); // Sort by StationId (max .. to .. min)
var c = list.OrderByDescending(P => P.Rooms.Max(Q => Q.Id)); // Sort By Room Id (max .. to .. min) Stations with max RoomId are first.
var d = list.OrderBy(P => P.Rooms.Min(Q => Q.Id)); // Sort By Room Id (min .. to .. max) Stations with minimum roomId are first.
var e = list.OrderByDescending(P => P.Rooms.Max(Q => Q.Beds.Max(Z => Z.Capacity))); // Sort by Bed capacity (max .. to .. min) Stations with maximum capacity first (I can use `Sum` over `Max` to tell that I wanna maximum Bed capacity stations in total. replace this: Q.Beds.Sum(Z => Z.Capacity)
IEnumerable<Bed> beds = list.SelectMany(P => P.Rooms.SelectMany(Q => Q.Beds)); // Merge all beds in all rooms from all stations
var f = beds.OrderByDescending(P => P.Capacity); // Sort in Beds only by capacity (max .. to .. min)
```

Every scenario is permitted.
For enterprise scale in suggest [sieve library](https://github.com/Biarity/Sieve).